# adding knn fit to plot in R

Tags: r, plot, knn

~Beginner in R~
I have the following code for a data set that has variables: price, mileage, and color. I have plotted a basic plot of x=mileage and y=price, and fitted a linear regression line to the plot.

```
cd = read.csv("https://bitbucket.org/remcc/rob-data-sets/downloads/susedcars.csv")
cd = cd[,c('price','mileage','color')]
n = nrow(cd)
set.seed(99)
pin = .75 #percent train (or percent in-sample)
ii = sample(1:n,floor(pin*n))
cdtr = cd[ii,]
cdte = cd[-ii,]
dim(cd)
plot(cd$mileage, cd$price, xlab="Mileage", ylab="Price", pch=16,cex=.8)
abline(lm(cd$price ~ cd$mileage), col="red", lwd=2)


## FITTING KNN
pred_knn=knn(data.frame(cdtr$mileage), data.frame(cdte$mileage), cl=cdtr$price, k=50)
```

I am trying to fit a line using pred_knn to the plot so that my plot looks like this:
[image]

However, I am not sure how to go about adding the kNN fit to my plot

Comment: What fit statistic do you want to place in the plot?

Comment: You cannot use `price` as your class argument since it is not a factor.

Answer (score 0):

As dcarlson mentions in the comments, it looks like you're using `class::knn` to predict a continuous variable, when it's meant to be used for classification (i.e. categorical responses).

The `FNN` package allows for kNN regression. Does this help:

```
library(FNN)
pred_knn = FNN::knn.reg(train = cdtr[2], test = cdte[2], y = cdtr[1], k = 50)
plot(cdte$mileage,cdte$price,, xlab="Mileage", ylab="Price", pch=16,cex=.8))
ORDER = order(cdte$mileage)
lines(cdte$mileage[ORDER],pred_knn$pred[ORDER])
```

[image: plot]